# Ember trigger action between child components

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my Ember app, I have a parent component 'A' which has two child components 'B' & 'C'
My question is:
How do I trigger an action from component B to component C (i.e. communication betwen the 2 child components)?

Just to add, `this.sendAction` from B to C is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. It's that simple. However there are other ways to achieve the same goal.

The basic pattern should be:

1. component `B` triggers an action on component `A`.
2. component `A` changes a value that is bound to component `C`.
3. now component `C` knows that the action happened.

Thats the general ember flow: *DDAU* (Data down Actions up).

If you want some encapsulation you can use contextual components, to *group* component `B` and `C` together and give them a shared state.

---

A short example:

```
{{component-b onsomething=(action 'myAction')}}
{{component-c state=state}}
```

now inside `component-b` you can do `get(this, 'myAction')('newState')`. inside component `A` (the parent) you have the action `myAction`:

```
myAction(newState) {
  set(this, 'state', newState);
}
```

inside `component-c` you can for example use a computed property to calculate something depending on the state:

```
shouldDisplaySomeButton: computed('state', {
  get() {
    return get(this, 'state') === 'newState';
  }
}),
```